# The relation between pointcloud and rgb data in gazebo

Tags: gazebo, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone, I designed a robot in gazebo. The robot is equipped with a depth camera Kinect. That is, the file "libgazebo_ros_openni_kinect.so" is called.

Is the output RGB image corresponding to the point cloud? (For example, does the top left corner of the point cloud correspond to the top left pixel of the RGB image?)

Please help me

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/396388/the-relation-between-pointcloud-and-rgb-data-in-gazebo/) by [kankanzheli](https://answers.ros.org/users/96081/kankanzheli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-02-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe the same frame is used as the origin of both the depth and rbg sensors.

If you need a more realistic model that includes the baseline between different sensors (e.g. the IR and RGB), consider looking at these models for [realsense](https://github.com/intel/gazebo-realsense/blob/master/models/realsense_camera/model.sdf) and [kinect](https://github.com/iit-DLSLab/sensors-description/blob/master/urdfs/sensors/kinect.gazebo.xacro) cameras. They define individual frames/plugins for each sensor

---

Originally posted by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) with karma: 1567 on 2022-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kankanzheli](https://answers.ros.org/users/96081/kankanzheli/) on 2022-02-18**:
The Kinect camera I'm using on the. So I want to confirm whether the information obtained from "/rgb/ image_raw" and "/ depth_registered / points" correspond. That is, "/ depth_registered / points" is equivalent to the result of adding x, y and z coordinate information to color information(same as image from "/ rgb / image_raw").